# $this->url returns only the module path

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2.2.4 to create an mvc application.

I have a module called `DrinkManangement` and inside of it i have a controller called `DrinkController` and an action called `drinkQueryAction`.

from a view phtml called `add-inventory` i'm trying to add the url to a form action attribute.

i'm using the following code:

```
$drink_query_form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('drink', array('action' => 'drink-query')));
```

the output of the `$this->url` command only returns `/drink-management` that is the path of the module. but it doesn't return `/drink-management/drink/drink-query`.

what am I missing here ?

thanks

## update

ok it's probably related to my route configuration but i have no clue how to fix it

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'drink' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                // Change this to something specific to your module
                'route'    => '/drink-management',
                'defaults' => array(
                    // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                    // the controllers for your module are found
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DrinkManagement\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Drink',
                    'action'        => 'add-drink',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                // specific routes.
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: What's the definition of the route `drink`?

Comment: updated main post with route configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should understand first how routes work. You have a "root" route called `drink`. This route has a single child called `default`. Now is `drink` a literal route. That means, there are no parameters in this route and it's always a static url `/drink-management`.

The child-route `default` is a segment route, which you can give parameters. So if you use the child-route in a view helper, you can assign parameters with an array like `array('controller' => 'foo')`.

Now, the important part is you can point to this child route by using `/` and its parent. So your default can be reached via `drink/default`.

A TL;DR:

```
$this->url('drink/default', array('action' => 'drink-query'));
```

PS. A comment on your naming: I would advise you to rename your routes so they make more sense. In a way, `drink` is your route and that's fine. The child route `default` is confusing as it is no default in general, but just a catch-all for your drink controller. It makes more sense to merge it into the `drink` route. Then you have a single route where you can specify an action (and the controller just remains the same):

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'drink' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/drink-management[/:action]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DrinkManagement\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Drink',
                    'action'        => 'add',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Now you have a drink route which you can give an action and it just stays on the drink controller:

```
$this->url('drink'); // to /drink-management
```

Or an action:

```
$this->url('drink', array('action' => 'query')); // to /drink-management/query
```